# Ajax working on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My autocomplete ajax code for a form is working in localhost but not on the server:

```
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        alert("My First JavaScript1");
        $(".auto").autocomplete({
            alert("My First JavaScript2");
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 2
            //width: 400
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I added to the comment the datepicker script so maybe there is a download&load script issue between scripts. Datepicker works fine by the way and alert functions I called are for understanding if the input in the form calls the function but there is no alert showing up so I take it does not get into there. How can I fix it?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>

Comment: Additionally, "search.php" correctly generates json code:
[{"label":"Anaa(French Polynesia) Anaa","value":"Anaa"}]